# Laravel, ovverride attribute names not work

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to use the login and registration form on the same page, but I have a conflict with the errors of the two forms. To solve I changed the ID and NAME attribute in my input fields in "register_mail", "register_user" and "register_password" and then, from the controller I entered this code:

```
        $validator = Validator::make($data, [
        'register_name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'register_email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        'register_password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
    ]);
    $validator->setAttributeNames([
        'register_name' => 'name',
        'register_email' => 'email',
        'register_password' => 'password',
    ]);

    return $validator;
```

unfortunately, every time I get an error because the register_mail field does not exist on the database.

Comment: You are renaming the validator attributes not the request attributes. show us the code where you insert into the database.

Comment: are you trying to modify the default `RegisterController` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to modify the default `RegisterController`, you should modify the `create()` function - since `setAttributeNames` won't affect the `$data` array:

```
class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    //...

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'register_name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'register_email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'register_password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['register_name'],
            'email' => $data['register_email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['register_password']),
        ]);
    }
}
```